# MySQL fatal error 1236 when swapping in new master, “master has purged binary logs”

Tags: mysql, replication, mysql-5.7, gtid

Our situation: we have three MySQL 5.7.23 replica servers attached to a MySQL 5.7.23 master server running in EC2 instances in AWS. All the servers are fine and GTID replication is working properly. We wanted to increase the size of the EBS volumes by launching a new replica, and then taking one of the existing replicas with already-enlarged volumes and setting it to be the new master. However, every time we do this, we get this error:

> Got fatal error 1236 from master when reading data from binary log:
>   ‘The slave is connecting using CHANGE MASTER TO MASTER_AUTO_POSITION =
>   1, but the master has purged binary logs containing GTIDs that the
>   slave requires.’

Our only option at that point is to switch the old master back in and let the original replicas catch up again. This is fine, but we have a lurking issue here where if the master ever does go bad, we're in danger of losing the entire cluster because we seemingly can't swap in a new master without issues.

The first time we tried this we had a server ID collision and the cluster was left without a master for a minute or so, so we assumed this was the cause of the problem. But we just tried again after ensuring all the server IDs were fine, and the new master was picked up by all the replicas fine but still threw the same error. We've also checked the expire_logs_days setting and made sure they're the same on all servers; this has no effect either, even if we wait a week before trying the operation again (expire_logs_days is set to 3 on all servers).

Our ability to collect information on this error is limited because we're doing this in a production environment and ideally we should be doing this with zero downtime. Any ideas?